# How to make my wordpress site to be able for user to download and upload files?

Tags: wordpress

I want to make a website from which users can upload and also download files which other users uploaded. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assign user subscriber/contributor role. Allow only media access to that role. There are even few plugins available but i won't suggest any as i haven't personally used it. Lock other access to that role. May be look at this article.
https://geekflare.com/allow-contributor-add-wordpress-media/